# Device detection connected to PC using C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How can I detect the connected devices into a Computer using C++? I can use windows programming facility, but .Net functionality is not allowed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't do it using C++ per se, you can use it with some OS API for C++

Comment: Do you want to enumerate all connected devices, or to detect when a new device is connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to handle WM_DEVICECHANGE message. When wParam = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL, new device is detected.

Answer (score 1):

The [SetupDi* (device manager) APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549791.aspx) can be called from C++.

If you want information about hot-plugged devices, you'll want to combine this with Alex's suggestion of `WM_DEVICECHANGE`, which tells you when to call SetupDi* again.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have written a code snippet using SetupDi* according to your suggestion. I have added Setupapi.lib in the linker section. When I attempt to run, I got the error, "The procedure entry point SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW  could not be located in the dynamic link library SETUPAPI.dll". I think, it is trying to link dynamically with setupapi.dll, but I have added static library and the program should use this. Could you please help me to fix the problem?

Comment: @user: MSDN says `SetupDiGetDeviceProperty` needs Vista or later. What version of Windows are you running?